# python - function not returning full output

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Im trying to get the model no of a switch from show inventory then set a integer to the no of ports the switch has. ive tried to make the result go onto one line and then search that with regex (the regex works i tested it on http://regexr.com/)

It doesn't look like my function is returning the full inventory, its getting cut off. it should return the below

```
Switch#sh inventory
NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C2960X-24PS-L"
PID: WS-C2960X-24PS-L  , VID: V01  , SN: XXXXX
```

This is the output im getting

```
Switch#
Switc
Object is: terminal length 0
Switch#sh inventory
NAME:
Inventory is:
Port Count is: 0
```

and this is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko
import time
import sys
import re

# For debugging only
#paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)

#
interface_regex = "interface GigabitEthernet[1-5]\/0\/"

def Send_Command_and_Get_Response(command, reponse, result):
    # Send the su command
    shell.send(command)

    # Create a new receive buffer
    receive_buffer = ""

    while not reponse in receive_buffer:
        # Flush the receive buffer
        receive_buffer += shell.recv(1024)

    # Print the receive buffer, if necessary
    if result:
        print receive_buffer

    return receive_buffer   

# VARIABLES THAT NEED CHANGED
ip = '10.X.X.X'
username = 'root'
password = 'XXXX'
port = 3010

# Create instance of SSHClient object
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Make sure that we add the remote server's SSH key automatically
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())


# initiate SSH connection
client.connect(ip, username=username, password=password,port=port, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
print "SSH connection established to %s" % ip

# Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
shell = client.invoke_shell()


print "Interactive SSH session established"
time.sleep(1)
shell.send("\r\n")
output = shell.recv(1000)
print output


# Disable more
Send_Command_and_Get_Response("terminal length 0\n", "#", False)

objInv = Send_Command_and_Get_Response("sh inventory\n", "#", False)
strInv =""
strInv.join(objInv.splitlines())

intPort = 0
if (re.match("WS-C.*24", strInv)):
    intPort = 24
elif (re.match("WS-C.*48", strInv)):
    intPort = 48

print "Object is: " + objInv
print "Inventory is: " + strInv
print "Port Count is: " + str(intPort)


# Close the SSH connection
client.close()
```

Comment: It's bad form to write `not a in b`.  Instead, you should use `a not in b`.

Comment: that seems to have fixed the output, the objInv string is now populated but the strInv is emtpy

Comment: any ideas on this? struggling alot...

Answer (score 0):

replaced new lines and breaks and used find instead of regex and its fixex!

```
objInv = Send_Command_and_Get_Response("sh inventory\n", "#", False)
print "Object is: " + objInv

strInv = str(objInv)
strInv = strInv.replace('\n','').replace('\r','')

intPort = 0
if (strInv.find('WS-C') >-1 and strInv.find('-24') >-1):
    intPort = 24
if (strInv.find('WS-C') >-1 and strInv.find('-48') >-1):
    intPort = 48
```